# Generate Dynamic Anchor Link based on JSON

Tags: javascript

From the text content I wanted to create Link tags dynamically,

Below is my code,

```js
const source = `Hello World`;

function tagGenerator(str, linkText) {
  const result = [];

  const arr = str.split(linkText);
  arr.forEach(textPart => {
    result.push({
      type: "TEXT",
      text: textPart
    });
    result.push({
      type: "LINK",
      text: linkText
    });
  });

  result.pop();
  return result;
}

console.log(tagGenerator(source, "World"));
```

With the above code, I'm getting the expected result.

But issue is, I'm getting an additional empty getting added.

I'm not sure why I'm getting that. Please help.

Comment: `"Hello World".split('World')` outputs `['Hello ', '']`. That second element in the resulting array is what is giving you the _additional empty_.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-edd3e8

Comment: Can you please attach the expected output, its really hard to understand this way